# Multiple requests at the same time but with different values in Json

Tags: json, jmeter

Below json body is posted:

```
"entries": [<br/>
{
  "tag1": {
    "id": 75
  },
  "tag2": 1,
  "tag3": {
    "id": 75
  }
},
{
  "tag1": {
    "id": 73
  },
  "tag2": 1,
  "tag3": {
    "id": 73
  }
}
]
}
```

I want to fetch data from csv and post to json body in single request. 
Sample csv will look like as following:
tag1,tag2,tag3
75,2,000000075
73,5,000000073

> tag1,tag2,tag3
>   75,2,000000075
>   73,5,000000073

I am new to Jmeter. Please help me.

Comment: Using CSV data set config you can read and pass the data from CSV to post request

Comment: But that data will get posted in different threads. I want to pass all this data in single thread

Comment: what you provided is example for 1 request, does CSV have multiple requests? and what is the expected behavior for different users?

Comment: No there is only 1 request. For different user behavior would be same. We will use same csv for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways which I can think of.

1- Use multiple csv for input variables.

2-Use single csv for input variables.

3- Use random csv data set config or jp@gc - Variables from csv.

So, plan will be.. Thread Group>CSV Data Set Config>HTTP Request>View Results Tree

I am showing option 2, single csv,place variables like shown below:-

tag1, tag2, tag3, tagX

75,2,0000000753,XXX

......

.......
Tag x -if any other variable is there.

So, first run will get all the values in a single request for multiple variables. It means all variables need to be put in a single line in CSV to send them in a single request.